# initialize member variable of base class inside child class and use in other class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Hi i have a Base class containing one string member as belows :

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    public String test;
}
```

Child class extending base class where i wish to initialize the test value.

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass 
{
    public void initialize()
    {
        System.out.println("inside constructor of ChildClass.");
        this.test="stringtest";
    }
}
```

Test class where i wish to use the value of test variable of base class:

```
public class TestClass extends BaseClass 
{
    public void test() 
    {
        new ChildClass().initialize();
        System.out.println(this.test);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestClass().test();
    }
}
```

Now my above code is printing null inside test class. why so? although i have initialized the test variable in child class? am i going wrong somewhere in java concepts?

Comment: You're creating a *new instance* of `ChildClass` and initializing that - not *this* instance. Additionally, please try to get used to *not* using public fields, as early as possible...

Comment: Hi all thanks for the reply!!! I would like to take this discussion further. what i wanted is that my child class was just suppose to initialize the test variable of base class and then i wanted to use the test variable of base class in my other classes as it is. so how should i go about to achieve this? i don't want to make instances of my child class in test class. TIA

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean, I'm afraid. It's not obvious why `TestClass` extends `BaseClass` at all.

Comment: @Mrunal You seem to be thinking in terms of non-object oriented programming . The only values a subclass could modify would be the ones in its own instance, unless you use `static` members (please don't do that unless you've got a good reason). Another option could be passing in to the subclass a reference to an Object holding the value you want to initialize there.

Comment: @JonSkeet see i have a container which contains member variables(in this case Base class containing test variable). i have set of setter classes which initialize the member variables of container class. i have another set of classes which extends the container class and use the value which was set by the setter classes. that is what i wish to achieve through my above dummy code

Comment: @MrunalGosar: Well you've just restated what your dummy code does, but not really *why* you're doing it...

Comment: @XaviLópez can you point out some code snippet for your second suggestion? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you create new `ChildClass` but you aren't setting it in a variable. then you print `this.test` which is never set.

when you are in `test` method you are in `TestClass` instance:

[image]

you are creating and setting a `ChildClass` class

[image]

but then you are printing the `TestClass` `test` member

[image]

if you just want to create `ChildClass` and use it do

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void test() 
    {
        ChildClass cls =new ChildClass().initialize();
        System.out.println(cls.test);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestClass().test();
    }
}
```

or if you want to extend `ChildClass` do

```
public class TestClass extends BaseClass 
{
    public void test() 
    {
        initialize();
        System.out.println(this.test);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestClass().test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two instances of `BaseClass` in the example you posted. One is the one instantiated with `new ChildClass()` and the other one is instantiated by the `main()` method (`TestClass`). Each one of them, being a subclass of `BaseClass`, has its own `test` member (they are different variables with different values).

Remember that the `this` keyword always references the instance in which it is used.

In this case, `System.out.println(this.test);` is accessing the `test` property of the `TestClass` instance created in the `main` method.

You need to access the `test` property of the other instance. You could do so by keeping a reference to the `ChildClass` instance and accessing the `test` property afterwards:

```
    ChildClass instance = new ChildClass().initialize();
    System.out.println(instance.test);
```

You might find the following Java Tutorials page useful: [Using the this Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Also take into account that `TestClass` doesn't need at all to extend `BaseClass`. You could keep accessing `instance.test` because it is a `public` member, but you should consider making the field `private` and provide getter and setter methods. See the following question for relevant information on this: [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1568091/851811)

Comment: can you post a code snippet. where the base class has the test variable. child class has the setter of this test variable. and test class has the getter of this test variable. please note that once the test variable is set then i should be able to access the same value in all other test class which are extending the base class. how can i achieve it. i am trying it but not able to make out the design as to how to keep things?

Comment: @Mrunal Is there any specific reason to take the inheritance approach? Take into account that every instance of a class or subclass will have its own values for the variables. Mayber you'd be better with [composition](http://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/851811) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`new ChildClass()` and `new TestClass()` are 2 different objects even if they are extending common `BaseClass`.

Having a common `BaseClass` as **super class** *doesn't mean* that it **shares** the non static fields of it, with all the instances of its different subclasses

This would have worked if `test` was `static` (shared class field) in `BaseClass`

Answer (score 0):

You need a instance of `Child Class`

```
ChildClass cls =new ChildClass().initialize();
System.out.println(cls.test);


this is referring to the Test Class instance.
```